# Starting a question with 'Could you' vs. 'Can you'?

Tags: grammar

What is the proper word to use when asking the question below:

> **Could** you please send your mobile number?

or

> **Can** you please send your mobile number?

Is one of those better than the other for some reason? Or are they about the same?

Comment: Why is your title asking about email but your question body asking about mobile numbers?

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit this question. To @user23929: In the future, avoid asking a question that asks, "Is this sentence correct or not?" or, "Which one of these is correct?" Instead, try to make it a more general question that would interest other English learners besides yourself. Also, when asking for a comparison between two sentences, highlight the difference. More tricks [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) (read through the answers, too). Also, don't forget to do some [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=could+you+vs+can+you), and share what you find.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> Could you please send **me** your mobile number.

I would regard *could* as more polite than *can* in this context. There is probably no *proper* way. All are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine grammatically, but it appears that you are aiming for a relatively formal setting in which case "Could" is slightly more formal-sounding. Neither would be incorrect, however.

"Could" also implies more of a polite request which may be refused, rather than a polite order, although this is a soft implication and does not make "Can" rude.

I would generally suggest using "Could" although I'd perhaps change the word order as the following flows better and sounds most like a polite request.

> Please could you send me your mobile number?

Comment: Using _would_ is a possibility, too: _Would you please send me your mobile phone number?_

Comment: That would sound very strange to me, and sounds slightly passive aggressive or demanding

Comment: It might, depending on the context. But consider: _It was nice meeting you yesterday in the cafeteria. That was a great conversation. I'd really like to arrange another meeting sometime, if you don't mind. Would you please send me your cell phone number?_ That doesn't sound too 'demanding' to me.